# Finding the expected value of a geometric distribution shifted by a constant

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose that for a random variable $X, \mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 0, k \geq c$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = k) = (1 - p)^{k - c}p$ otherwise. How can we find the expected value for $X$? Sure, $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k\mathbb{P}(X = k) = \sum_{k = c}^{\infty}k\mathbb{P}(X = k) =  \sum_{k = c}^{\infty}k(1 - p)^{k - c}p$. But how do we continue from here? By ratio test the series does converge (makes sense), but I am not sure how to manipulate the series into a nice "clean" form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pmf is the following

$$P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-c}p$$

With $k\geq c$ that is $k=c,c+1,c+2,...$

This evidently means that the  mean is simply

$$E[X]=\frac{1-p}{p}+c$$

---

This because if we consdider the Geometric rv

$P(Y=k)=(1-p)^{k}p$ defined in $k=0,1,2,3,...$ and with mean $E[Y]=\frac{1-p}{p}$ your rv is $X=Y+c$